# FCPX Libraries - Smart Folder (Mac OSX)

Tags: osx, fcpx

Is there a way to create a Smart Folder that contains just FCPX Libraries (.fcpbundle)?

Not sure what parameters to use for the 'Kind is Any' or 'Name Contains' search fields.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can choose "Kind" and set it to "Other" then type "Final Cut Pro Library" into the text field. Like this:

[image]